# HTML / Javascript: Multiple choice widget for nested sets

Tags: javascript, html, widget, nested-sets, multiple-choice

In my current project, I have a nested set of regions composed as follows:

```
World
   Europe
      Germany
      Italy
      Spain
      ...
   America
      ...
   ...
```

I'm looking for a Javascript based choice-widget for HTML which provides multiple selections for nested sets. If the user for instance selects "Europe", all sub-regions have to be selected. Otherwise, redundant selections would be possible. You can see this kind of widget in some installers when selecting packages.

I didn't find anything useful yet

Comment: If I think about it, the implementation would be not too much effort and maybe the best solution. Why didn't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few months ago I looked for the same answer. After hours of searching I wrote my own code based on `onchange` events and `each` loops (jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
http://codeassembly.com/Simple-chained-combobox-plugin-for-jQuery/

Comment: That's perfect for single selections. But I need multiple selections. The user can select multiple regions, but "Europe" and "Italy" doesn't make sense as two different selections